# Let A be a 3×4 matrix and the coefficient matrix of a system of linear equations. Let b⃗ be a column vector in R3

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Question:

Let A be a 3×4 matrix and the coefficient matrix of a system of linear equations. Let b⃗  be a column vector in R3

1). Find an example of such a matrix A
and a vector b⃗  such that the system with augmented matrix [A|b⃗ ]
has infinitely many solutions.

2). Find an example of such a matrix A
and a vector b⃗  such that the system with augmented matrix [A|b⃗ ]
has no solution.

3). Is there an example of such A
and b⃗  such that the system with augmented matrix [A|b⃗ ]
has a unique solution? If so, give one, if not, why not?

4). Give an example of a coefficient matrix A
such that [A|b⃗ ] has a solution for every vector b⃗  in R3.

My answers:

**1)** I got this as a possible answer.

1  2   3   4  |0

5  6   7   8 |0

9  10  11  12 |0

**2)**

3 -2 0 1 | 1

1 2 -3 1 | -1

2 4 -6 2 | 0

I just don't know what to do for 3 and 4. If 1 and 2 are wrong, any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

3) Your matrix is a 3x4 matrix so number of equation is 3 and number of unknowns is 4. It can never have unique solution, you can always vary the fourth unknown on $\mathbb{R}$ once you have other three unknowns fixed, according to your choice of vector b.

4) The columns of your matrix are $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$. The system $x_1v_1 + x_2v_2 + x_3v_3 + x_4v_4 = b$ is consistent that is it has solution when b is a linear combination of $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$. As we want to generate $\mathbb{R^3}$, ($b\in \mathbb{R^3}$), so we need $span \{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4 \} = \mathbb{R^3}$, so choose three linearly independent columns for your matrix and leave the fourth arbitrary. For each b, you may get multiple solutions.

For more read about Rank of a matrix and Gaussian Elimination, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem) and [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations) and [this lecture notes.](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~lee/linear/sys-eq.pdf) This may help you understand better.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if column space is greater that the row space you have more variables than ecquations, in that sense your answer will never be a point (unique solution), in the best case you will have a line, it all depends on the linear dependance of the row space vectors, consider that for make the choice of the matrix's numeric coeficients you're looking for